# run next function after setTimeout done

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make it work? pls help.

```
function first() {
    setTimeout((function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
    }), 1000);
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
$.when(first()).done(second()).done(third());
```

first() runs as last function, i need as first

Fiddle here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hqphbhx3/)

Comment: did you try writing the code at the end in the timeout function itself?

Comment: those setTimeout are asynchronous so we doesnt know which one would be executed first

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am not sure why are you doing this, but if you want to execute them synchronously, you can place the 2nd and 3rd function call inside `setTimeout` :

```
function first() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
        second();
        third();
    }, 1000);
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
first();
```

Answer (score 18):

## EDIT:

You can now also try [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (doesn't support IE) awaiting the timeout promise before executing first second and third. `fireEvents` is our async function in this example. Notice how since `fireEvents` has the `async` keyword before the function that it is able to use the `await` keyboard. Await keywords allow you to await the finishing of a promise. Here there is a small promise wrapper using the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) constructor around setTimeout which is returned from the function `timeout` this `timeout` function is awaited inside of the async function `fireEvents`.  The commented numbers below show order of the execution. For deeper knowledge on Promise execution order you can read Jake Archibald's wonderful article [Tasks, microtasks, queues and schedules](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).

```js
function timeout (ms) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res,ms));
}

function first () {
  // $('#q').append('first <br>'); 
  console.log("first");
}

function second() {
  // $('#q').append('second <br>');
  console.log("second");
}

function third() {
  // $('#q').append('third <br>');
  console.log("third");
}

async function fireEvents () {
  // 2
  console.log("2. before await")
  await timeout(1000);
  // 4
  console.log("4. after await")
  first();
  second();
  third();
}

// 1
console.log("1. started");
fireEvents().then(()=>{
  // 5
  console.log("5. done")
});
// 3
console.log("3. after fireEvents");
```

---

## Original Answer

You don't need jquery's deferred when you can use javascript [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) instead.

```js
function first() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout((function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
        resolve("Stuff worked!");
    }), 1000);
});
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
first().then(second).then(third);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="q"></div>
```

Another way of executing the last line `first().then(second).then(third);`
is by making it

```
first().then(function () {
  second();
  third();
});
```

which you can do since you know the second and third functions are synchronous functions unlike the first function which is asynchronous.

**EDIT**: The reason behind using a javascript promise or in guest271314's answer a jquery defer is because if you wanted to reuse first but call something besides first or second after it's done in a different part of your code you could just write something to the effect of

```
first().then(function () {
  fourth();
  fifth();
});
```

And you would be writing that without changing the function for first.  Promises and deferreds make async code more reusable.

Answer (score 4):

Try utilizing `$.Deferred()` within `first` , return `$.Deferred()` jQuery promise when `setTimeout` completes , call `second` , `third` within `.done()`

```js
function first() {
  var d = new $.Deferred();
  setTimeout((function() {
    $('#q').append('first <br>');
    d.resolve()
  }), 1000);
  return d.promise()
}

function second() {
  return $('#q').append('second <br>');

}

function third() {
  return $('#q').append('third <br>');
}

$.when(first()).done([second, third]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id='q'></div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hqphbhx3/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to isolate the functions, try this. You pass in a `callback` to the `first` function, and when the timer times out, that callback is called. In that callback you can call `second()` and `third()`.

```
function first(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
        callback();
    }, 1000);
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
first(function(){
   second();
   third();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems: Your `first` function (and the rest of them, for that matter) are not returning promises, so you can't use `done`. If you were using promises, `done` would seal the promise and not allow you to chain another `done` call. For this setup, you would be better off nesting your function calls like:

```
function first() {
    setTimeout((function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
        second();
    }), 1000);
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
    third();
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function first() {
    setTimeout((function() {
        $('#q').append('first <br>');
        second();
        third();
    }), 1000);
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}
first();
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function start() {
    setTimeout((function () {
        $.when(first()).done(second()).done(third());
    }), 1000);
}
function first() {
    $('#q').append('first <br>');
}
function second() {
    $('#q').append('second <br>');
}
function third() {
    $('#q').append('third <br>');
}

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked unexpectedly, I just added an arrow function as third parameter and it was executed right after setTimeout finished

```
setTimeout(() => {
    first();
    second();
    }, 
    1000, 
    () => {
        third()
    }
);
```